# Why does my point and shoot camera lose the date/time when I turn it off?

Tags: battery, date

My point and shoot camera used to keep the date when turned off. Now, every time I turn it on,
I have to reset the date and time. What could cause this?

Comment: Hi Dennis, could you please indicate what brand and type your digital camera is? That might help track down the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The internal clock in a camera requires power to keep running. In some cameras, the clock runs off a separate battery from the main one. This secondary clock battery (often a small button cell) may have died and needs to be replaced.

For an example of this type of battery replacement, see [the ifixit.com guide on replacing the clock battery in a Canon Powershot A590](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Canon+PowerShot+A590+IS+Clock+Battery+Replacement/3841).